# In 2011 two 14-year-old girls held an 11-year-old boy down and stripped him completely naked

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

The girls then uploaded a video of him being held down naked to Youtube and they weren't prosecuted, why is this?

https://web.archive.org/web/20110604124555/https://www.winknews.com/Local-Florida/2011-06-01/Online-video-shows-Fort-Myers-boy-being-bullied

Answer (score 4):

### Because the relevant law enforcement decided not to

In the US (and indeed in all common law jurisdictions), law enforcement and prosecutors have discretion over when and if to lay charges by considering such things as the wishes of the victim, the prospects of success and whether charges would be just in the circumstances.

At best, this allows a measured response to the particular situation. At worst, it enables discrimination and persecution. Either way it solves the problem of allocating limited resources to comparatively unlimited need.

Comment: According to the linked article, the police said "the girl would have faced misdemeanor battery charges, but that the boy's mother has refused to press charges. She wants the girls' parents to hand out a punishment instead."  Is that a decision of "relevant law enforcement" or of the boys' mother?

Comment: @phoog that would be considering the wishes of the victim

Answer (score -1):

Because no charges were made by the responsible parent.

> [2011-06-11: Online video shows Fort Myers boy being bullied](https://web.archive.org/web/20110604124555/https://www.winknews.com/Local-Florida/2011-06-01/Online-video-shows-Fort-Myers-boy-being-bullied)
> ...
> Fort Myers Police says the girl would have faced misdemeanor battery charges, but that **the boy's mother has refused to press charges**. She wants the girls' parents to hand out a punishment instead.
> ...

Comment: The state can press charges in most jurisdictions if the parents refused. If boys did the same thing to a girl the state would have pressed charges or forced the mother to press charges.

Comment: The state can raise taxes and legalize prostitution and do all sorts of things it chooses not to. If the question is why didn't they exercise their discretion a certain way, the answer is simple: They didn't want to. Unfortunately, it can't be answered as a legal matter.

Comment: @John And who would the state charge? The parents? [Florida Legal Ages Laws - FindLaw](https://www.findlaw.com/state/florida-law/florida-legal-ages-laws.html)

Comment: @MarkJohnson There are a variety of offenses available in the juvenile justices system.

Comment: @ohwilleke But they obviously decided not to untertake any action in this case (and after 11 years it is to late).

Comment: @MarkJohnson Certainly the state didn't bring charges and didn't have to. The point is merely that the state could have done so if it wished. There are several answers discussing why the state doesn't bring charges when it could have because a victim or parent doesn't want to press charges.

Comment: @ohwilleke Yes and that is exactly what the original article stated.

Comment: @MarkJohnson the point is that the victim's parent's desire not to charge the perpetrator is not determinative.  A complete answer, therefore, is that the police or the prosecutor chose to respect the parent's desire not to charge the perpetrators.  They could have chosen not to respect that desire, in which case charges would have been brought even though "no charges were made by the responsible parent."

Comment: @phoog The point is that when, after 11 years (9 years after the statute of limitations a for first degree misdemeanor in Florida has expired), no undertaking has been made from the official side: then it never will be. The original article made it clear that the Fort Myers Police respects that decision. **What more needs to be written?**

Comment: It's discrimination against the boy because the police wouldn't have "respected the parents desire not to charge the perpetrators" if boys did this to a girl. Had this been done to a girl the police would have pressed charges regardless of what the parent wanted. Only giving misdemeanor battery charges for a child being stripped naked, held down and having a video of themselves naked put online is pathetic. If boys did that to a girl they would be in prison.

Comment: @John That is a matter that needs to be delt with within the Florida jurisdiction. Based on reports during the last weeks, this could be problematic.

Comment: @John why do you think the police would have behaved differently had the victim been a girl and the perpetrators boys?

Comment: @phoong Because the victim would be female. Do you honestly believe the police would let boys get away with stripping a girl naked, holding her down and putting a video of it on Youtube? It would never happen. There would have been protests and national outrage if the police didn't charge the boys.